# Aggregate different modules based on scala binary version

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to cross build a project for (2.11, 2.12) where some of the subprojects should not be built for 2.12 because their transitive dependencies are not yet released for 2.12. Specifically Spark for Scala 2.12. The root project's aggregate looks like

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(vegas, spark, flink, macros).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(noPublishSettings: _*)
```

Is there some way to detect the `scalaBinaryVersion` in the `#aggregate` and aggregate a different set of projects if the crossbuild is trying to produce a 2.12 artifact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no direct way to do it. As a workaround, you may want to get a similar effect by making `spark`'s `libraryDependencies` empty and skipping `compile` and `publish` when `scalaBinaryVersion` is 2.12:

```scala
// tested on sbt 1.1.0

lazy val spark = (project in file("spark"))
  .settings(
    // ... other settings ...

    // Empty out libraryDependencies when scalaBinaryVersion is 2.12.
    libraryDependencies :=
      (if (scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.12") Seq.empty else libraryDependencies.value),

    // Skip compilation and publishing when scalaBinaryVersion is 2.12.
    skip in compile := scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.12",
    skip in publish := scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.12"
  )
```

The `skip` task key allows us to skip some task. From `inspect skip`:

> `Task`: `Boolean`
>
> For tasks that support it (currently only `compile`, `update`, and `publish`), setting `skip` to `true` will force the task to not to do its work.  This exact semantics may vary by task.

However, in contrast to `compile` and `publish`, `skip in update := scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.12"` does not work here. From [sbt Reference Manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#Caching+and+Configuration):

> 5. Overriding all of the above, `skip in update := true` will tell sbt to never perform resolution. ... Also, (note that) update itself will immediately fail if resolution has not been allowed to run since the last clean.